# Gulp to connect server on production

Tags: angularjs, gulp, webfaction

I'm trying to add my angular project to production with webfaction. However I'm not sure how to do it as there isn't really any documentation with webfaction regarding gulp and angular. 
I understand that theres a difference between development and production servers, but what I don't understand is the process of using gulp-connect for production...

This is what I have to start my local server in my gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
    root: './app',
    port: 8000,
    fallback: './app/index.html'
  });
});
```

How can/do I use gulp-connect on production?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You don't. Use a proper web server like express.

Comment: @Seiyria So you're telling me there's no way to get my angular project up on production this way? I'll have to bring in express.js into my angular project?

Comment: @Seiyria I'm willing to forget using gulp. I just want to put my angular project up on production.

Comment: I'm suggesting that gulp is not the tool you should be using in production. You should be using express or some other web server in production.

Comment: @Seiyria Im only asking this as my project is complete and I need to deploy it. I was under the impression that gulp could handle it. While adding express might work; its something that I'm not sure how to handle as my project is built, ready to go and adding express might mess up everything. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules such as `gulp-connect` designed for development (fast start, easy to setup), but not for production (lack of security and performance).

If you haven't any backend on your project (if this is only angularjs project, no server-side and db), then you no need to use any complex hosting platform. You actually required only for static server (which will provide your assets for user).

You are able to use any of static hosting, like [github pages](https://pages.github.com/).

If you're want to up your own server, you can up you angular project with things like nginx.

Of course you can write your own server with express, for example (lots of tutorials).

Comment: Hey thank you for posting a helpful answer. And It's static content. I'm using my own json to fetch some data. I guess what I'm confused about is getting it up and running. Normally there's a command to start up my angular project on my local like `gulp serve`. How will it start up on the production server whether with nginx or github pages?

Comment: If you use some third-party service, like github pages, there no need to start with command - it will be already up and running. In case of your own server like nginx, there is several options, depend of your requirements and your os. It may be for example just running the executable file of nginx. http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html